# Monolog: Send error logs by mail causes an extra mail for every error sent

Tags: php, symfony, monolog, symfony-mailer

For every error log sent by mail we get another extra email with 2 lines of smtp debug log messages.

- Newly created symfony demo (`symfony new --demo`)
- Configured monolog to send error messages by mail as in the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/logging/monolog_email.html)
- symfony/monolog-bundle `3.7.0`
- Symfony Versions `5.2.1` / `5.2.9` / `5.3.0-RC1`,
- PHP 7.4.13

```yaml
# config/packages/prod/monolog.yaml
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: critical
            handler:      deduplicated
        deduplicated:
            type:    deduplication
            handler: symfony_mailer
        symfony_mailer:
            type:       symfony_mailer
            from_email: 'error@example.com'
            to_email:   'error@example.com'
            subject:    'An Error Occurred! %%message%%'
            level:      debug
```

Monolog sends error messages as expected, but every mail is followed by a second one with this content:

```
[2021-05-26T10:49:47.683298+02:00] app.DEBUG: Email transport "Symfony\Component\Mailer\Transport\Smtp\SmtpTransport" stopping [] []
[2021-05-26T10:49:47.722980+02:00] app.DEBUG: Email transport "Symfony\Component\Mailer\Transport\Smtp\SmtpTransport" stopped [] []
```

- no extra mail in `dev` or `test` environments
- no extra mail when setting the framework config `test: true` in `config/framework.yaml`

Any ideas how to get rid of this extra email in production mode?

PS: [There's also an open issue in the Symfony MonologBundle](https://github.com/symfony/monolog-bundle/issues/405).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68943441/why-symfony-monolog-send-error-extra-mail

Comment: Like mentioned in the linked GitHub issue, a workaround would be to exclude the "mailer" channel. That's what we've done. See: https://github.com/symfony/monolog-bundle/issues/405#issuecomment-1069040234

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the linked GitHub issue by [@raziel057](https://github.com/raziel057), a workaround would be to exclude the "mailer" channel.
https://github.com/symfony/monolog-bundle/issues/405#issuecomment-1069040234

```yaml
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: critical
            handler:      grouped
            channels:     ["!mailer"]
        grouped:
            type:    group
            members: [streamed, deduplicated]
        streamed:
            type:  stream
            path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
        deduplicated:
            type:    deduplication
            handler: symfony_mailer
        symfony_mailer:
            type:       symfony_mailer
            from_email: "%mailer_app_sender%"
            to_email:   "%mailer_team_receiver%"
            subject:    "An Error Occurred!"
            level:      debug
```